# What is meant by map/set iterator not decrementable? How to make map.rbegin()->first work?

Tags: c++, reverse-iterator

I am trying to get the last element in my map of map_of_bit_to_parent

```
map<long long, long long> ::reverse_iterator itr_rel = map_of_bit_to_parent.rbegin();
long long total_parent_rels = itr_rel->first;
```

But assignment itself caused a run time error " map/set iterator not decrementable"

How to make such assignments?

Comment: Are you sure the map is not empty? Check `map_of_bit_to_parent.empty()` before trying to using a past-the-end iterator.

Comment: map is not empty. I have initialized it. Debugged already

Answer (score 1):

*Always* test the validity of an iterator before accessing data through it.

```
map<long long, long long> ::reverse_iterator itr_rel = map_of_bit_to_parent.rbegin();
long long total_parent_rels = 0;
if ( itr_rel != map_of_bit_to_parent.rend() )
{
   total_parent_rels = itr_rel->first;
}
```

Comment: I just need to assign rbegin()->first (the last key in the map) to the variable total_parent_rels

Comment: @seno71625, what should happen when the map is empty?